# Manipulate and ListPlot in a single chart

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I have "Manipulate[Plot ... " Where I can adjust my variables. In that chart I want to include datapoints. Right now I have two separate graphs:

```
 Manipulate[Plot[volatility[k, beta, alpha, rho, v], {k, 20, 45}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.3}], {b, 0,1}, {a, 0, 1}, {p, -1, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]

ListPlot[{{31.174, 0.1751}, {36.5, 0.20}, {27.88, 0.16}, {41.28, 
0.23}, {24, 0.154}}, PlotRange -> {{20, 45}, {0, 0.3}}]
```

How can I gather those plots in one chart. "Show" function does not work here

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Have you seen [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html)?

Comment: Yeah, I have mentioned it in my question. But maybe I am using it wrong. How would you use it?

Comment: Like the first example in the docs: `Show[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3.5}], ListPlot[{1, 4, 9}]]`? How were you using it?

Comment: Show[Manipulate[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3.5}]], ListPlot[{1, 4, 9}]]
Remember that I need the manipulate function

Comment: But it will, won't it, if you put ***your*** expressions in?

Comment: No It won't. It says:

Show::gcomb: Could not combine the graphics objects in Show[

Comment: This is my code:
Show[Manipulate[
 ' Plot[vol[k, b, a, p, v], {k, 20, 45}], {b, 0.1, 1}, {a, 0.1, 1}, {p,
    0.1, 1}, {v, 0.1, 1}], 
 ListPlot[{{31.174, 0.1751}, {36.5, 0.20}, {27.88, 0.16}, {41.28, 
    0.23}, {24, 0.154}}]]'

Comment: That doesn't look like `Show[Plot[..], ListPlot[..]]`...(Put it inside the `Manipulate`)

Comment: I don't follow you. Where to put the manipulate?

Comment: Outside, if the other goes inside: `Manipulate[Show[Plot.., ListPlot..],..]`

Comment: I have tried that form ^^

Comment: Use `PlotRange -> All` and make sure `alpha`, `beta` and `rho` have numeric values.  And that `volatility[..]` is defined.  If I do that, I get something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/E0dKC.png

Comment: That exactly what I am looking for, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think 'show' function is the way to go. Try this structure:

```
 Manipulate[ Show[ Plot[],ListPlot[], PlotRange-> ],{} ]
```

Your code will be something like that:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
        Plot[volatility[k, beta, alha, rho, v], {k, 0, 40}],   
        ListPlot[{{31.174, 0.1751}, {36.5, 0.2}, {27.88, 0.16}, {41.28,0.23}, {24, 0.154}}],
        PlotRange -> {{0, 45}, {0, 0.3}}
     ],
 {beta, 0, 1}, {alpha, 0.1, 1}, {rho, 0.1, 1}, {v, 0.1, 1}]
```

Comment: And I assume that b, a, p  and v are meant to be beta, alpha, rho and v?
If it is in a financial context (which I am pretty sure that it is) then I think my assumption is correct

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[volatility[k, beta, alpha, rho, v], {k, 20, 45}, 
    PlotRange -> {{20, 45}, {0, 0.3}},
    Epilog ->
      {Red, AbsoluteThickness[5], 
       Point[{{31.174, 0.1751}, {36.5, 0.20}, {27.88, 0.16}, 
              {41.28, 0.23}, {24, 0.154}}]}],
  {b, 0, 1},
  {a, 0, 1},
  {p, -1, 1},
  {v, 0, 1}]
```

Of course, I could not test this since you didn't provide a working example.